# Problem determining Color Saturation

Tags: colors, hsv, hsl

I am writing a tool that will attempt to determine which of the [known colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) is "closest" to some user-chosen color (from the full RGB gamut). I am noticing that the values returned by Microsoft's GetHue and GetBrightness appear to have the same values as the HSL Hue and the HSL Lightness values computed by the [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) article. But Microsoft's GetSaturation does not appear to consistently equate to any computed value (HSL, HSV, HSI).

Question(s)

1. What color model does Microsoft use for its GetHue, GetSaturation, and GetBrightness functions?
2. Has anyone found errors in the [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) computations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed Chris Haas' algorithm in [RGB to HSL and back, calculation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793729/rgb-to-hsl-and-back-calculation-problems) and found that my derivation of the algorithm was flawed.

1. What color model does Microsoft use for its GetHue, GetSaturation, and GetBrightness functions? HSL. In the Color Dialog component, the HSL values are transformed from the range [0,1] to the range [0,240].
2. There do not appear to be any errors in [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), only those that I introdiced.