# Generate Color between two specific values

Tags: c++, colors

I have a lowest speed `Color` and a highest speed `Color`

I have another variable called `currentSpeed` which gives me the current speed. I'd like to generate a `Color` between the two extremes using the current speed. Any hints?

Comment: try [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) for all 3 rgb values

Comment: @KaiIskratsch If you want to be more accurate: raise all RGB values to the power of 2.2, interpolate *those*, then raise them to the power of 1/2.2.

Comment: my comment was only intended as a very simple solution, but never intended as a perfect solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to linearly interpolate each of RGB (because that is probably the format your colours are in).  However it can lead to some strange results.  If `lowest` is bright blue (0x0000FF) and `highest` is bright yellow (0xFFFF00), then mid way will be dark grey (0x808080).

A better solution is probably:

- Convert both colours to HSL (Hue, saturation, lightness)
- Linearly interpolate those components
- Convert the result back to RGB.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793729/rgb-to-hsl-and-back-calculation-problems/4794649#4794649) for how to do the conversion to and from HSL.

To do linear interpolation you will need something like:

```
double low_speed = 20.0, high_speed = 40.0;  // The end points.
int low_sat = 50, high_sat = 200;            // The value at the end points.
double current_speed = 35;

const auto scale_factor = (high_sat-low_sat)/(high_speed-low_speed);
int result_sat = low_sat + scale_factor * (current_speed - low_speed);
```

Two problems:

- You will need to be careful about integer rounding if speeds are not actually `double`.
- When you come to interpolate hue, you need to know that they are represented as angles on a circle - so you have a choice whether to interpolate clockwise or anti-clockwise (and one of them will go through 360 back to 0).

Comment: I assume you are not asking "how do I do linear interpolation"?

Comment: This makes assumptions about what the asker wants to do, of course.

Comment: Yup.  I don't see that as problem.

Comment: Well I'll find how to to it. Thanks.