# How to get color name, accent color and lighter or darker ratio from RGB value in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get string of color information from an image, but how to get that information from RGB value like this one:[Tool tip in excel color selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOasV.png)

Please help me or tell me what can I do to get string information from RGB color.

Comment: None of that exist in C#. The best you can do is `Color.ToString()` but that will only output text for KnownColors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.knowncolor?view=net-7.0. Just FYI: That excel dialog is based on the Theme: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-in-word-or-excel-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904#bkmk_create with only 12 base colors and then 6 gradients generated for each color. That is a palette that won't be able to capture any of the color range found in an image.

Comment: There are 256*256*256, so over 16 million possible RGB colors. It seems unlikely that any language has such many words for colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to map color values to either names or known [X11 colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.colors?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). But there is nothing builtin for office like colors.

To do any more advanced processing you likely need to convert RGB to [HSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793729/rgb-to-hsl-and-back-calculation-problems). This give you separate channels for Hue, Saturation, and Lightness. You would then need to define ranges for each name, i.e. `if(hue > 100 && hue < 140) return "green"`

But that will likely quickly become complicated, since a specific color is in effect section of a color volume, and different people will disagree about where the borders are. How dark does something need to be before you would call it black? So I would take a long hard think about what you really want to do, and if there are any other ways to do it.